# How can I create a loop for Chat Bubbles?

Tags: html, css, loops, chat

I want to develop a loop for chat bubbles. Every time I write a message, a bubble should be created and be on the right. When the chat partner replies, the message should be on the left in the bubble. How can I develop this loop?

My current code is this one:

```html
<div class="Webview">
  <div class="message_container" id="myForm"></div>
  <form class="send_container">
    <input id="textField" type="text">
    <p>
      <input type="button" id="theButton" value="Nachricht absenden!" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').innerHTML=document.getElementById('textField').value" />
    </p>
    <h3>
      <div id="div"></div>
    </h3>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by loop?

Comment: Plz check https://onaircode.com/html-css-chat-box-examples/ if you are trying to create the bubble designs

Answer (score 1):

OK, it is not add messages to the DOM in loops, but just add message on Enter on the trigger that sending the message.

If you want to add value from Text Field such as text input, 
You probably want to do two steps:

1. Getting the value from the input
2. Inject the value into a balloon template (html) and then into the DOM.

Then, you should add Javascript scope into your html or just include js file that contain the following function:

```js
function addMessage() {
  // Add XSS validation
  const $messages = document.getElementById('myForm');
  const $textElement = document.getElementById('textField');
  const newMessage = '<div class="message-balloon">' + $textElement.value + '</div>';
  $messages.innerHTML += newMessage;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="theButton" value="Nachricht absenden!" onclick="addMessage()" />
```

In jQuery it will be like this (in the js scope of course):

```js
$("#theButton").off('click').on('click', function() {
  e.preventDefault();
  const $messages = $('#myForm');
  const $textElement = $('#textField');
  const newMessage = '<div class="message-balloon">' + $textElement.value + '</div>';
  $messages.html += newMessage;
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="theButton" value="Nachricht absenden!" />
```

Hope it helps :)
Good luck